# winerror32 python renaming file

Tags: file, rename

Im using FTP connection, after closing connection, i need to work with file. How can I do that?

```
import ftplib, os, time

host = "ftp_host"
ftp_user = "ftp_user"
ftp_password = "ftp_pass"
filename = "Mon.xlsx"

filename2 = "Monitor9564.xlsx"
os.rename(filename, filename2)

con = ftplib.FTP(host, ftp_user, ftp_password)

f = open(filename2, "rb")

send = con.storbinary("STOR " + filename2, f)

con.close

time.sleep(2)
os.rename(filename2, filename)
```

But im getting an error

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'Monitor9564.xlsx' -> 'Mon.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your file handle before attempting to rename your file. You can issue `f.close()` before your second rename method, or you can let Python deal with proper file handle scopes for you:

```
# code...
with open(filename2, "rb") as f:
    send = con.storbinary("STOR " + filename2, f)
    con.close()
os.rename(filename2, filename)
```

Also, why are you renaming your file only to rename it back to its original name?